Passing through /dev/mem into gVisor container
In standard Docker (runc) by default, /dev/mem is not mounted. It's possible to pass it through with --device /dev/mem:/dev/mem to make it visible within the container. However, reading is still not permitted (Operation not permitted) unless the CAP_SYS_RAWIO capability is added with --cap-add CAP_SYS_RAWIO. After that, processes in the container can read from it.
In gVisor (Docker with runsc) it is also not mounted by default, but when passing it through with --device /dev/mem:/dev/mem reading from it fails with No such device or address instead of Operation not permitted and adding the CAP_SYS_RAWIO capability does not change that.
What is the additional mechanism in gVisor that prevents reading from /dev/mem and can this be enabled?
